# PySpark is Writing Large Single Parquet Files instead of Partitioned Files

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, parquet

For most of my files, when I read in delimited files and write them out to snappy parquet, spark is executing as I expected and creating multiple partitioned snappy parquet files.

That said, I have some large .out files that are pipe-separated (25GB+), and when I read them in:

```
inputFile = spark.read.load(s3PathIn, format='csv', sep=fileSeparator, quote=fileQuote, escape=fileEscape, inferSchema='true', header='true', multiline='true')
```

Then output the results to S3:

```
inputFile.write.parquet(pathOut, mode="overwrite")
```

I am getting large single snappy parquet files (20GB+). Is there a reason for this? All my other spark pipelines generate nicely split files that make query in Athena more performant, but in these specific cases I am only getting single-large files. I am NOT executing any repartition or coallesce commands.

Answer (score 0):

check how much partitions you have on `inputFile` dataframe. Seems like it has single partitioned.

Seems like you are just reading a CSV file and then writing it as parquet file. check the size of your CSV file, seems like it really large.

```
inputFile.rdd.getNumPartitions
```

if it's one. Try repartition dataframe.

```
inputFile.repartition(10) \\or 
inputFile.repartition("col_name")
```

Comment: Just strange that its outputting a singular file without running repartition(1) or coalesce(1) on the dataframe beforehand. I have other CSVs that I am reading it that output multiple part files by default without needing to manually repartition.

Comment: did you check how many partition you have on `inputFile` ?

Comment: Yes, on the file in question I only have one partition (hence the one file). But in all the other files this runs against there are dozens of partitions generated. Just strange that files can be the same size and spark chooses to write to a single partition for large files when I have a server with over 10 workers. I guess I will have to check the file size and if the partitions returned == 1, then I need to repartition based on the file size so that I can query more efficiently in Athena.

Comment: you input partition size depends on how many files you are reading. did you check how many CSV files are you reading? if you are reading one big file of 20GB and will try to write in parquet you will get one big 20GB file only.

Comment: I figured it out. The files being delivered by this vendor have encoded characters that are non-standard. If I remove them for some reason Spark partitions the output files in a manageable fashion as expected.